# Python pyautogui Windows 10 control shift end combo fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing some code to copy data from an Excel file, but I cannot get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code used below that did not work:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'end')
```

or

```
pyautogui.press('ctrl')
pyautogui.press('shift')
pyautogui.press('end')
pyautogui.release('ctrl')
pyautogui.release('shift')
pyautogui.release('end')
```

also

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.keyDown('end')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
pyautogui.keyUp('end')
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also why create an auto-gui to copy from excel?  Seems like you'd be over complicating it.  Why not use Pandas and filter out what you want copied?

Comment: same issue here.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, you need the number lock off.

With the number lock on, pyautogui seems to choose "end" from the 1-numpad instead of the "end" key. But with the number lock off, it highlights to the end in Notepad or Notepad++.

This seems like an ambiguity pyautogui should be resolving, but it is a tricky case.

If you want to check if the number lock is on before sending `pyautogui.press('numlock')`, see this question: [Python 3.x - Getting the state of caps-lock/num-lock/scroll-lock on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160100/python-3-x-getting-the-state-of-caps-lock-num-lock-scroll-lock-on-windows)

Comment: thank you so much! I have been struggling with this issue for a while!

Answer (score 2):

Below line worked fine

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','shiftright','shiftleft','end')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use "ctypes library" to check the keyboard's numlock key state and either disable it or switch hotkeys accordingly.

Getting **numlock key state** code:

```py
# ctypes accesses C functions through Python, interfacing with platform libs.
import ctypes

def is_numlock_on():

    """
    Use the GetKeyState function from the user32 DLL to check the state of the numlock key.

    A virtual-key code is a unique value assigned to each key by the operating system.
    The virtual-key code for numlock key is 0x90.
    """

    return True if ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState(0x90) & 1 else False
```

After this, you can press numlock key to disable it depending on its current state but **I suggest you be independent of numlock**.

So, instead, you should **use conditional hotkeys** based on the current state of numlock:

```py
COND_HOTKEY = "ctrl, shiftright, shiftleft, end" if is_numlock_on() else "ctrl, shift, end"

pyautogui.hotkey(*COND_HOTKEY.split(", "))
```